# Returning an image from a Django view using django-sslserver

Tags: python, django, ssl, python-imaging-library, django-extensions

I'm trying to return an image from a Django 1.11 view while using django-sslserver and Pillow. Here's a minimal view I made for testing.

```
def get_image(request):
    img = Image.open('oh_noes_cat.png', mode='r')
    response = HttpResponse(content_type='image/png')
    img.save(response, 'png')
    return response
```

In my template I use:

```
<img src={% url "get_image" %} />
```

In urls.py, I use:

```
url(r'^get_image.png', get_image, name='get_image')
```

The image response works fine with Django runserver but fails under both django-sslserver and runserver_plus from django-extensions. What I see in Chrome is a broken image icon and the error "ERR_CONTENT_LENGTH_MISMATCH".

When using django-sslserver I get the error:

```
[26/Dec/2017 18:55:39] "GET /get_image.png HTTP/1.1" 200 0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 138, in run
    self.finish_response()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 180, in finish_response
    self.write(data)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 279, in write
    self._write(data)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 453, in _write
    result = self.stdout.write(data)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/socket.py", line 593, in write
    return self._sock.send(b)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/ssl.py", line 861, in send
    return self._sslobj.write(data)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/ssl.py", line 586, in write
    return self._sslobj.write(data)
ssl.SSLEOFError: EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:1844)
[26/Dec/2017 18:55:39] "GET /get_image.png HTTP/1.1" 500 59
```

Does anyone know how I can make an image response work with django-sslserver or a similar solution for supporting SSL in a Django development environment? I've searched but not been able to find an example of someone having this particular problem.

Thanks

Comment: Does this solution help? "Ok, so the easiest way for you to fix this up is to run `python3 -m pip install pyopenssl pyasn1 ndg-httpsclient`. That should fix your problem, but if it doesn't we can pursue more aggressive options." from https://github.com/requests/requests/issues/3006#issuecomment-226784234

Comment: Installing pyopenssl, pyasn1, and ndg-httpsclient doesn't help, unfortunately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it's not completely clear what Image.save() does in this context, could you try doing it this way?

```
def get_image(request):
    image_data = open('oh_noes_cat.png', mode='r').read()
    return HttpResponse(image_data, content_type="image/png")
```